# GPUImage2 - How to Get Processed Video URL To Save in Device?

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

Anyone please help me to get the processed video URL from GPUImage2 Library after applying video filter?

```
do {
    let bundleURL = Bundle.main.resourceURL!
    let movieURL = URL(string:"sample_iPod.m4v", relativeTo:bundleURL)!
    movie = try MovieInput(url:movieURL, playAtActualSpeed:true)
    filter = SaturationAdjustment()
    movie --> filter --> renderView
    movie.start()
} catch {
    fatalError("Could not initialize rendering pipeline: \(error)")
}
```

Thanks in Advance,
James

Comment: The reason is to gain URL is to save it in our device. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
 func applyfilters(){
    do {
        // movie input
        movieInput = try MovieInput(url: inputVideoUrl, playAtActualSpeed: true, loop: false)

        // movie output
        movieOutput = try MovieOutput(URL: outputVideoUrl, size: videoSize, liveVideo: false)             

        // pipeline
        movieInput.addTarget(currentFilter)
        currentFilter.addTarget(renderView)
        currentFilter.addTarget(movieOutput!)

        movieOutput!.startRecording()
        movieInput.start()

    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
 }

 //Below function should be called after the filter is applied on full video. If you call this function before video ends it will not generate the rest part of the video.

 func stopVideoRecording(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    movieOutput?.finishRecording {
        completion?()
    }
 }

 //To save video
 func saveVideo(){
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputVideoUrl)
    }) { saved, error in
        if saved {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
 }
```

**Usage Example**

```
  applyFilters()

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:.now()+AVAsset(url:inputVideoUrl).duration.seconds, execute: {
       stopVideoRecording{
            self.saveVideo()
       }
  })
```